# Can there be differences between .NET 4 and .NET 3.5 when running a .NET 3.5 process

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

We are experiencing different behaviour when running our .NET 3.5 process on 2 environments.

One has .NET 4 installed while the other has only 3.5

Our application is compiled against the .NET 3.5 libraries.

Can there (or should there) be any differences in behaviour in this scenario?

Which runtime is used when a 3.5 process is run on the machine with .net 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any further specification, the process uses the .NET 4.0 runtime. You can change this behavior by setting the [supported runtime version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) in the application configuration file of your application.

```
<configuration>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

This setting will instruct to use the .NET 2.0 runtime.

Comment: So, the .NET 4.0 runtime executes my 3.5 process? is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You can check this with Process Explorer of Sysinternals which version of the CLR hosts your application

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.0 has all the things available with 3.5 and has some added libraries. when your. Net 3.5 application runs in   .Net 4.0 it consumes only those libraries required for your application to run. So there is no issue whether the system has 3.5 or 4.0 framework.

Comment: This only involves the LIBRARIES. What about the runtime? (does it contain fixes/improved performance/other changes that may affect code execution?)